# PHP str_replace with file_put_contents, cache interaction

Tags: php, caching, replace

Not sure why but having an issue here, this is the last line in my PHP, through a global.php file, I'm saving scraped data in the cache folder. In the below situation, I'm saving it as "s&pcurrent." In my output, I'm getting a "+" that I don't want, which is from the source content. Likewise, I created a str_replace to get rid of the + with a blank space ' '

However, it doesn't work, I must be formatting it wrong somehow. Any tips? Thanks so much.

```
file_put_contents(globalVars::$_cache_dir . "s&pcurrent", str_replace('+', ' 
', $ret_[0]);
```

Comment: Do you have some samples of the text that is causing you grief?

Comment: `$ret_[0]);` should be `$ret_[0]));`. You missed an ending parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks Hasib! Silly of me to forget that.